# Generating observation from the multivariate gamma, exponential and weibull distributions

Tags: r, statistics

With known parameters i am able to generate observations from the multivariate normal and t distributions using mvrnorm and rmvt commands respectively in R.
My question is how can i generate observations from the multivariate gamma, exponential and weibull distributions with similar commands if they are available in R?

Comment: `help(Weibull)` and `help(GammaDist)` and `help(Exponential)` and you may want `help(family)` as well

Comment: http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help+generate+multivariate+gamma#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20generate%20multivariate%20gamma+page:1+mid:c637hdl2rbt4y24m+state:results